# How can 'View Page Source' be different to page rendered?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

We (at work) had a design company build a static website in html5, and I've tied in ASP.Net code behind to make it functional.
The log in screen contains a form thus:

```
<input class="ui-input-text ui-body-c" id="txtUsername" placeholder="Username&hellip;" value="" runat="server" />
<input class="ui-input-text ui-body-c" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password&hellip;" value="" runat="server" type="password" />
<span class="select-decoration submit login">
       <input class="submit-button" id="btnLogin" value="Login" type="submit" runat="server" onserverclick="submitbutton_click" />
</span>
```

...and after validating the log-in I do a Response.Redirect to the 'home' screen.

The problem I have is although the page appears to load, if you 'View Page Source', the code presented is still the log-in page, the url in the address bar is still the log-in page; and since the log-in is at root and all contents pages are in a '/v2' sub directory, none of the paths to images are valid so nothing displays.

Oddly though, if you use the 'F12' tools in the browser, the html for inspection is the correct html. This behavior is true of IE 10, Firefox and Chrome.

I've tried both the true and false flags for Response.Redirect (mostly out of desperation, there is no further code to execute anyway) with no joy.

Everything I've found on here and google refers  to PostBackTriggers, but I'm not using an UpdatePanel so no joy there.

I'm convinced this is something to do with HTML5, but it's new territory for me so I'm floundering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're not actually setting a cookie or anything, and that if you refresh the home page after you've been validated, you will be sent back to the login page? If that is the case, the problem lies in that when you 'View Page Source', the browser isn't actually giving you the current HTML of the page you're on. It is actually getting it all from the server again, just like a normal request, the only difference is that the browser is now showing you the HTML instead of rendering it. This is also the reason that F12 developer tools DOM-inspector can show you the current HTML, since that is indeed showing you the current HTML in real time. I hope I'm being clear, and that I assumed correctly, I don't have a high enough reputation to comment. :)

Comment: Correct, I'm not setting a cookie and refreshing the home page does indeed reload the login page. I'm not sure I'm following what you're saying about getting all the html from the server again though... What would cause this behaviour?

Comment: To be brief, what's happening when you load the page normally, the browser sends a get request to the server, retrieving the HTML, and then rendering it, so it's pleasant for us humans to look at. When you append the URL in the address bar with 'view-source:' (which is what Chrome does when you select 'View page source'), the same thing happens, except the browser skips the last step, and just shows you the HTML. So when you view page source the browser does not think 'let me show him the current page's HTML', instead it thinks 'let's get all the HTML again, from the same place he got it from'

Comment: Thank you, so that explains why the view source is different to the actual page. My problem remains though... why does the Response.Redirect get the new page, render it, but then not actually change the url?

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer since it put me on the right path, and explained why the 'view source' was different to the current page. Thanks for your help.